# Maven surefire debug taking too long to start debugging in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I am using maven surefire debug plugin to debug the unit tests. Till yesterday, it used to take almost 1 min for the debug control to reach eclipse after I trigger it from the terminal. However, only for one of the repositories, it has taken starting almost 10-12 mins from today. Other repos are still taking less than a min. Any idea what the underlying issue can be? Any suggestions on how I can troubleshoot it further?
Sample command I am using :-

```
mvn clean test -Dquality.check.skip=true -Djasper.reports=none -Dcloud.provider.value=AWS  -Dtest=GridXTimeOfUseProcessorTest#processRequest -Dmaven.surefire.debug
```

Comment: Why not trying to execute the test from your IDE with debugging instead of callign via command line?